# Git push fails for large data

Tags: git, github, git-push

When I do a git push to GitHub of over 4GB of data I get this output.  I've tried 3 times and get the same error each time.  How can I solve this?

```
C:\Data\GitRepository\ABC\Master\ABC [master]> git push --verbose
Pushing to https://github.com/username/ABC.git
Counting objects: 1322, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
warning: suboptimal pack - out of memory
Compressing objects: 100% (1267/1267), done.
POST git-receive-pack (chunked)
error: RPC failed; result=55, HTTP code = 200 153.00 KiB/s
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (1321/1321), 4.26 GiB | 1.70 MiB/s, done.
Total 1321 (delta 238), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
C:\Data\GitRepository\ABC\Master\ABC [master]>
```

Comment: Why are you pushing 4 GB to GitHub? The [max repo size that they allow is 1 GB](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota#rule-of-thumb-1gb-per-repository-100mb-per-file). Why is your repo so big?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Since GitHub does not allow such large files or repositories, it simply hangs up](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota#rule-of-thumb-1gb-per-repository-100mb-per-file)